# Drawing a line by using long press gesture in ios

Tags: ios

I want to draw a line at that point where long press gesture occurred. I am using long press gesture on `UIImageView`.

I can get coordinates by using gesture object but don't know how to use these coordinates for drawing a line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to add a line on a view. if you want more custom drawing, then you can go for more customisation of drawrect method of a uiview custom class.

```
CAShapeLayer *line = [CAShapeLayer layer];

UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(387, 532);    
[path moveToPoint: startPoint];

CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(487, 532);        
[path addLineToPoint: endPoint];
[path stroke];

line.path = path.CGPath;
line.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
line.strokeColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
line.lineWidth = 3.0;

[self.view.layer addSublayer:line];
```

For more details please refer to below link:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIBezierPath

Comment: Its not working for me because in my case I am using UIImageView not UIView.

Comment: @user2923374 self.imgviewObject.layer addSublayer:line.  try this.